# Decrypt image using AES Algorithm with password

Tags: iphone, android, aes, encryption

hi guys could any one tell me how i can decrypt a image with password using the AES Algorithm.The Image has been encrypted in the iphone with some password.

Thanks in advance

Edit #1
   The thing is that the user will select some image from a iPhone app and encrypt it with user entered password and post it to server. And now what we need to do is to download the image from the server and decrypt with the same password and display the image to the user. And in iphone they have given the password with length 4 like 'test'. Hope you can understand better what i m trying to do.

In iPhone they have [followed this link](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/strong-encryption-for-cocoa-cocoa-touch.html)

Comment: Is this a programming question? Are you looking for something like the crypto library?

Comment: Question is not clear. Be more specific. Too many unknowns here. Provide more information

If it is from an iPhone, have you checked if the image format has no compatibility issues in Android?

Comment: @Andrew Anderson hi buddy i have update my question. hope you can understand it now... i m not having the compatibility issues... the problem i don't know how to decrypt the image with the given password.

Comment: Do you know the exact process by which it was encrypted in the first place? Encryption has lots of parameters. If you miss one, output will be unusable.

Comment: @glorifiedHacker: for sure it's programming question. Just added iPhone tag. Hopefully some iphoners knows answer based on AES library for iPhone...

Comment: hi guys i have added the link which has been followed the iphone people for the above process.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first you need to know the key which was derived from the password. Did they use PBKDF#2? How many rounds? AES doesn't have "passwords", it has keys.

Second, which mode was the image encrypted in? ECB? CBC? CTR? GCM?

If you have a `byte[]` of data, `SecretKey` of key, and `byte[]` of IV, and used CBC mode, you can use the following for the decryption:

```
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv)); 
ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(imageByte);
```

Since there are a ton of unknowns here, I can't proffer the exact solution.

Comment: i have posted the link using which they have implemented the encryption in iPhone..

Answer (score 1):

To decrypt image you'd need to know 2 things:

1. Key generation procedure details. Usually it's done using [hash calculation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) based on supplied password. Sometimes password can be reinforced using so-called [password salting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29). If so you'd need to know password salt. Basically:

   key=hash(password+salt)
2. Even if you know key also you have to know [ciphering mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation) (those mysterious ECB/CBC and so on). Basically operation mode means how encrypted blocks chained to each other.

Without those 2 parameters it's useless to decrypt - so *"Use The Source Luke!"*

Comment: Any chance you know the key generation details and ciphering mode of an iphone's stock encryption? Does it use salt?

Comment: @mikato For sure they ought to use salting. I don't think that Steve was hiring dumb guys...

I don't know details of iPhone key generation details, try to ask [these guys](http://www.elcomsoft.com/eppb.html)

Comment: Ha yeah, I have been reading up about Elcomsoft stuff already. I was hoping those details were external knowledge now. I may be working on extracting deleted text messages from an image of an encrypted phone if I think there's a chance, so that might be a little of what Elcomsoft's software does and a little something else. I don't expect it will be easy in any case.

Comment: I don't think they had any of this until ios 3 either so maybe Steve got better at hiring ;)